# Using script task to get data from webservice with ssis

Tags: vb.net, ssis

i use the in this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/01/28/consuming-web-services-in-ssis-script-task.aspx) to setup an script task in ssis 2008 r2 to pull some data from this [webservice](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/axis/services/Baseform?wsdl). The original web task in ssis do not work (not all wsdl features supported to use this webservice)

My problem is to get the main funktion in the script task to get run.
currently it looks like this

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim ws As New BaseformService
    Dim param As New RequestParameter

    ws.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("anonymous", "anonymous")

    param.corpus = "Autos"
    Dts.Variables("Return").Value = ws.execute(param)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

I save the result of the ping event to my variable "Result". But the task crashes. I should provide a user....

Any ideas?

```
Error: 0x1 at Script Task 1: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Please enter a username!
```

Comment: Don't suppose you could translate the German in that exception into English, could you?

Answer (score 0):

First, set up a Try/Catch/Finally block around the ws setup and execution. That way at lest you will not crash and at least set the result.

Then, set a breakpoint and see if you can get any additional details on the error condition. From what I can understand of the error, it looks like your web service doesn't like Anonymous.